# main camera not covering whole screen in unity3d

Tags: unity

I have been using unity and i got a problem where my main camera is covering only the first half of the floor i made.
camera position is left and the floor is rotated ,i m posting an image please help .
I have shown a player white coloured and an enemy pink coloured .player is not shown as you can see.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look at camera's clipping planes. Play with near and far and see what changes. Near plane tells camera where to start rendering the scene and far plane tells where to stop rendering.  Maybe your near plane is too far and parts of your level which are closer to your camera are not rendered. You could get more info from the [camera docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html)

Comment: i have already done that , it has no effect , i have changed all the camera position and done its still the same

Comment: There are 2 pink objects in the game scene but in the editor one of them is white. Is that an expected behavior of your game? You mentioned that only first half is covered. What are those halves?

Comment: there are 3 objects ,2 are pink and one is white ,in game view i can view both the pink but not the white .pink is ok no need to worry for that.i m asking for the white one which is located at left of the yellow path but slightly at a diffrence , which is not showing in camera..simple when i slide the top yellow wall it disspears its located at 0,0 that is it doesnot shows in game view